# reading data from secondary mongo database

Tags: java, mongodb

I am creating reports on `mongodb` using java . So here I need to use map reduce to create reports  .I am having  3 replicas in production . 
For reports queries I do not want make request to primary `mongo database` . I want to make request to only secondary replica ,So here if we use map reduce it will create a temporary collection.

1) Here is there any problem if i set read preferences as secondary
    for reports using map reduce? 
   2) will create temporary collection on
    secondary replica?
 
   3) Is there any other way to use secondary
    replica for report purpose since i do not want to create traffic on
    primary database?
4) will i get correct desired results since having
    huge data?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to just connect to the secondary directly, instead of connecting to the Replica Set with ReadPreference.SECONDARY_ONLY. In that case, it will definitely create a temporary on the secondary and you should have the correct results (of course!).

I would also advice you to look at the Aggregation Framework though, as it's a lot faster and often easier to use and debug than Map Reduce jobs. It's not as powerful, but I have yet had to find a situation where I couldn't use the Aggregation Framework for my aggregation and reporting needs.

Comment: @user2575166 If you think this answered your question, please accept the answer!

Comment: Hi Derick , could you please give reply for below link having few more doubts posted all queries on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614881/reading-data-from-only-secondary-mongodb-using-map-reduce-queries   thanks in advance